# How can I call an overriden methods of all my Subclasses in Java?

Tags: java, parent-child, extends

I have the class A, B and C.
B is a Subclass of A. In my Main class C, I create a few instances of B.
Now is my question, how I can call the method do() of the subclasses in C.

Comment: A little code in the question would help.

Comment: can you put your code here.

Comment: `b.do()` if the method is public, what is the problem and why isn’t this working for you?

Answer (score 3):

You can call the methods of class A inherited by class B like this from your main:

class A:

```
public class A {
    private int temp;
    public void doMethod(){
        System.out.println("doing stuff in A\n");
    }
}
```

class B:

```
public class B extends A {

}
```

class C:

```
public class C {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here
        B obj=new B();
        obj.doMethod();

    }
}
```

output:

```
doing stuff in A
```

You could also override the doMethod() in class B and then call it from main exactly like shown above

```
   public class B extends A {
    @Override
    public void doMethod() {
        System.out.println("Doing stuff in B\n");
    }
}
```

then the output would be

```
Doing stuff in B
```